# before_filter order in parent and child controllers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4, controllers, before-filter

I'm developing a multitenant application using subdomain. See my controllers

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :handle_subdomain

  def handle_subdomain
    @tenant = Tenant.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
    if !@tenant.nil?
      MultiSchema.set_schema_path("#{request.subdomain}, public")
    else
      render_404
    end
  end
end

class ObjectivesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_objective, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

- If I do the request 'test.url/objectives'(call to
  `ObjectivesController#index`) works great!
- If I do the request
  'test.url/objectives/1'(call to `ObjectivesController#show`) does not
  work. I get the error:

  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ObjectivesController#show
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "objectives" does not exist at character 29 : SELECT "objectives".* FROM "objectives" WHERE "objectives"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1

Same result for `edit` and `destroy`.
The objectives table does not exists. I think that this is due to first run `ObjectiveController#set_obectives` so it doesn't find objectives table on `public` schema. I need run first `ApplicationController#handle_subdomain` to set the correct schema and then run `ObjectiveController#set_obectives`. How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't it due to using both old and new filter macro?

Comment: I tried but the error keeps

Comment: Well... I restarted the server and work fine now... WTF?!?!

Comment: Was it in production?

Comment: No, it was in develop environment.